# New index in lookup table

Tags: sql, indexing

Here are my 2 SQL tables:

1. **tblElevators**
   ElevatorID (int, pk);
   Location (nvarchar);
   Manufacturer (nvarchar);

*This table have nearly 7000 records, and Manufacturer field contains values from lookup table below (some values are Null)*

1. **tblManufacturers**
   Manufacturer (nvarchar, pk);

Now I want to insert a ID column in second table (tblManufacturers) which will be Integer and PrimaryKey. Since it have only 40 rows, I'll put PK manually (1,2,3...40)

My question is - how I can change all existing Manufacturer values in tblElevators to new Integer value, withot manually going thru all the data and figuring out what "Manufacturer Name" now is ManufacturerID.

Thank you

Comment: As a hint for future questions: **SQL** is just the Structured Query Language - a language used by many database systems - SQL is **NOT** a database product... it is always helpful to know what database system and which version you're using ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not really sure what you want. But it sound like you want something like this:

```
UPDATE tblElevators 
SET tblElevators.ManufacturerID=tblManufacturers.ManufacturerID
FROM tblElevators 
JOIN tblManufacturers
   ON tblElevators.Manufacturer = tblManufacturers.Manufacturer
```